# Dispatcher/Proxy (Client) Extensions for better throughput of WCF service

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

Need some expert opinion on this case study.

Problem Statement/Scenario:
My WCF client/proxy continually requiring some lockup data from relevant WCF service. More precisely, I've a WCF service that provides Location data (City/Country etc) from a database (although data is cached on Service). Some how I want to avoid Serialization/DeSerialization (Object contains a lot of associated properties as well as inner objects) cost and service operation execution for better throughput.

Few days back I studied WCF behaviors/WCF extension methods.I found an interesting article on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx). After reading this article I thought this could help me to improve performance of my service. So before implementing this I want to confirm that either I'm thinking in right direction or any other solution can solve my problem.

I'm thinking to implement Dispatcher Extensions to solve this problem instead of Proxy (Client) Extensions. I've following queries?

I) Where (Proxy/Service level) I need to implement extensions? 
II) When implementing Dispatcher Extensions my call will not send to actual service and I'll save Serialization/DeSerialization cost. Right/Wrong?
III) Implementing Dispatcher Extensions in my case is also better, because why need not to bother about which proxy interface method call occurred as caching logic is on service side. Right/Wrong?

Please suggest me a better solution as I want to save Serialization/DeSerialization cost as well as I want to implement data caching.

Thanks in advance
/Rizwan

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I've incorporated WCF caching in the past:

1. Using Castle DynamicProxy to generate proxies for my ServiceContract interfaces. These dynamic proxies use interceptors to perform caching. If the data is not in the cache, the interceptor creates a real WCF client (a `ChannelFactory<TInterface>`) and invokes the WCF operation, then caches the result. I like this approach, because the caching implementation isn't really WCF specific.
2. Implement an IRealProxy for WCF which wraps the actual remote operations and performs caching/retrieval as necessary. In principal, this is similar to approach 1, but the implementation is specific to WCF (with remnants of .NET Remoting). I used this approach before migrating to #1. I migrated to approach 1 because approach 1 let me accomplish caching on both the client and the server in an implementation agnostic manner. At the time, I rolled my own RealProxy, but it looks like someone else has since done the same and posted the code: http://blog.ngommans.ca/index.php?/archives/31-Custom-Proxy-Generation-using-RealProxy.html

Comment: What will happen when multiple applications are using my service and each application have it's own proxy class cache data at there end and eventually data mismatch on service.

For example, Proxy1 call the Location Service and ask for location 'London' data, service serves Proxy1 call and give data to it and Proxy1 cached it. Now Proxy2 call the Service and update location 'London' data, service serves Proxy2 and will update data at there side and Proxy2 will cache it. Now Proxy1 called for the same location 'London' and find it at there local end and didn't know that data updated at Service?